# Threading with SQLite and python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to write data as fast as possible to a SQLite database using python3, and also have a tkinter GUI running.
I have two sensors that are reading data, and I would like to write these data to SQL. I am getting the error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: cannot start a transaction within a transaction
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Does a certain amount of time have to lapse before another transaction can occur?

Code:

```
import threading
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
import time
from datetime import datetime
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from dateutil import parser
import random

conn = sqlite3.connect('testDB.db', check_same_thread=False)

class GUI(Frame): # test tkinter GUI

    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.root = root
        self.button1 = Button(self.root, text="above", command = self.test_functionA)
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2 = Button(self.root, text="below", command = self.test_functionB)
        self.button2.pack()

    def test_functionA(self):
        pass

    def test_functionB(self):
        pass


def simulated_sensor1(a,b):
    unix = int(time.time())
    date = str(datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    x=1 #to keep while loop running
    cursor1 = conn.cursor()
    cursor1.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sensorA (unix REAL, 
    datestamp TEXT, value REAL)")

    while (x==1):
        simSensor1 = random.randint(a,b)
        cursor1.execute("INSERT INTO sensorA (unix, datestamp, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",(unix, date, simSensor1))
        time.sleep(1)
        conn.commit()
        print(simSensor1)

def simulated_sensor2(a,b):
    unix = int(time.time())
    date = str(datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    x=1 #to keep while loop running
    cursor2 = conn.cursor()
    cursor2.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sensorB (unix REAL, datestamp TEXT, value REAL)")
    while (x==1):
        simSensor2 = random.randint(a,b)
        cursor2.execute("INSERT INTO sensorB (unix, datestamp, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",(unix, date, simSensor2))
        time.sleep(1)
        conn.commit()
        print(simSensor2)

def main():
    threadA = threading.Thread(target=simulated_sensor1, args=(1,10))
    threadA.start()
    threadB = threading.Thread(target=simulated_sensor2, args=(1,10))
    threadB.start()
    root = Tk()
    ex = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: You many want to look at [sqlites-serialized-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850025/sqlites-serialized-mode)

Comment: Thanks @TianyunLing!
That looks like what I need (http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html), but I am too much of a beginner to understand how to implement it. 
Would I just use  cursor.sqlite3_exec() instead of cursor.execute()?

Comment: SQLite has no write concurrency; threads are a bad idea. To speed up many inserts, commit less often.